# jQuery selecting un-needed elements in objects of same class

Tags: jquery, class

complete beginner here. So I have two instances of this object in my HTML document.

```
<div class="newsItem cf sb br">
            <div class="closeButton right"></div>
            <div class="titles left">
                <div class="Title"><h3>{{Title}}</h3></div>
                <div class="Subtitle"><h5>{{Subtitle}}</h5></div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="imageContainer"><img src={{URI}} alt="" /></div>
            <div class="newsText"><p>{{Text}}</p></div>
            <div class="interactive">
                <div class="comment left sb br">Komentiraj</div>
                <ul class="right stcom">
                    <li><button class="star"><img src="images/icons/star.png" alt=""></button></li>
                    <li><button class="star"><img src="images/icons/star.png" alt=""></button></li>
                    <li><button class="star"><img src="images/icons/star.png" alt=""></button></li>
                    <li><button class="star"><img src="images/icons/star.png" alt=""></button></li>
                    <li><button class="star"><img src="images/icons/star.png" alt=""></button></li>
                    <li>0</li>
                    <li><img src="images/icons/speech.png" alt="bubble"/></li>
                </ul>
            </div>  
        </div>
```

The elements in the list that have the class star are supposed to imitate a star rating system. I need to make a jQuery function that lights up a star that is clicked and all the previous stars. My objects are defined only by the class newsItem, no id's. 
A friend of mine did it with the following code, but he used id's for his objects and had to copy the code for each object with a different id:

```
$("#slider").on("click", "#box1 .ButtonMore", function()
{
    var stars = $("#mainContainer #slider #box1 .star .cl .stars .ButtonMore");
    var x= stars.index($(this));

    for (var n = 0; n < stars.length; n++)
        $(stars[n]).removeClass("active");

    for (var n = 0; n <= x ; n++)
        $(stars[n]).addClass("active");
});
```

I've tried to modify this code to use with just the class, but no luck. 
My modification:

```
    $("#itemContainer").on("click", ".newsItem .star", function()
{
    var s = $("#itemContainer .newsItem .star");
    var x= s.index($(this));

    for (var n = 0; n < s.length; n++)
        $(s[n]).removeClass("active");

    for (n = 0; n <= x ; n++)
        $(s[n]).addClass("active");
});
```

When I got it to light the stars up, a click in the second object would light up all the stars in the first object, like they were all under the same list. I'm guessing that's because I'm using just classes and not id's. Is there any way to do this without id's, cause I don't want to clutter up my .js file and this knowledge would really come in handy in the future. It's schoolwork so I need to do it like this.

Comment: can you summarise what do you need.? I just read your post twice, but cant understand anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the star elements within the current newsItem, so try

```
$("#itemContainer").on("click", ".newsItem .star", function () {
    var $stars = $(this).closest('ul').find('.star'),
        index = $stars.index(this);
    $stars.slice(index + 1).removeClass('active');
    $stars.slice(0, index + 1).addClass('active');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QnDfF/)